# Load data to Salesforce using ADF SF connector

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

We are planning following to transfer data to Salesforce:
Data bricks to do logic transformation and put result in sql to use existing ADF Salesforce connector to load.
Want to know if ADF supports latest bulk Salesforce API which is Bulk API 2.0?
While creating linked service to Salesforce I don't see it in apiversionz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used Azure Data Factory. The ADF2 plugin available on marketplace is provided for free by "Simba Technologies". [Their page](https://www.magnitude.com/drivers/salesforce-odbc-jdbc) says it's on API v 45 at the moment, 8 releases behind so almost 3 years. You could try asking them but you aren't their customer directly so you don't have much leverage...

In theory it should be fine, the `ingest` endpoint [first appeared in API 41](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/create_job.htm).

Whether they implemented it - ultimately you will have to try it out. Prepare a big job (over 10K records), load it. Examine login history to check the API version used. Go to Setup, start searching "bulk" and check if there's a job or was it loaded old school way, 200 records at a time...

Answer (score 0):

ADF now has a built-in [Salesforce Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory). It uses Bulk API V1 but thats perfectly respectable - Bulk API V1 and V2 co-exist and V1 is better in some ways*

The ADF Salesforce Connector is pretty good but if you want to retrieve the results of a bulk load (which rows failed etc) you have to jump through a few hoops, see [blog post](https://www.codeulike.com/posts/2023/adf-salesforce) about it.

* re: Bulk API V1 and V2: I prefer V1 because it lets you retrieve results via the UI, but V2 doesn't. V1 lets you set a batch size but V2 doesn't, etc.